# Is there a way to send NotifyIcon notification when the application is closed in Winform?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I would like to know if there is a way to set NotifyIcon to send notifications at a time which will be scheduled once the app is open. The functionality should be to send notifications like in an alarm. So the user gets the notification even when the application is closed.

Comment: Do not close the application, just hide the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't. As the NotifyIcon is a control like others in your form and gets disposed when the form is closed.

However, you may `Hide()` (or `Visibility = false`) your form instead of `Close()`;